# How to use generic type

Tags: android, json, generics, gson

I have a JSON structure like this.

```
{
  "1.1": {
    "image": "image.jpg",
    "value": [
      {
        "1": {
          "name": "step 1",
          "values": [
            {
              "name": "string value",
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "name": "string value",
              "value": "120"
            }
          ]
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "Step 2",
          "values": [
            {
              "name": "string value 1",
              "value": "0.08"
            },
            {
              "name": "string value 2",
              "value": "0.04"
            }
          ]
        },
        "3": {
          "name": "Step 3",
          "values": [
            {
              "name": "string value 1",
              "value": "0.08"
            },
            {
              "name": "string value 2",
              "value": "0.02"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "1": [
          {
            "name": "name 1",
            "image": "image_conf.jpg",
            "value": "0.036"
          },
          {
            "name": "name 2",
            "image": "conf_two_four.jpg",
            "value": "0.039"
          },
          {
            "name": "name 3",
            "image": "conf_four.jpg",
            "value": "0.038"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "1": {
          "name": "name ",
          "values": [
            {
              "name": "string name",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "string name",
              "value": "40"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "formula": "formula"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I would like to use generics types, but I do not know how to parse that structure using Gson.

I have done this. (I have more than one object - "1.2", "1.3" and more.

```
public class Warm<T> {

    public Warm() {}

    public String image;
    public String name;
    public T value;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need generics here?

Comment: because for example, "value" could be a String or JSONArray

Comment: You can use a `JsonDeserializer` that unwraps your data as you need.

Comment: @Stepan so you just posted payload having string values only? Well, it's really not obvious. As @Miha_x65 is suggesting you, you might want to use `JsonDeserializer` registered to deserialize `Wrap<T>`. Take a look at Gson builder. See more at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer